# Can not deploy container on gcloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy the below container on gcloud:

> https://hub.docker.com/r/anthonydahanne/spring-petclinic/

Then, I do below steps:

1. I created a namespace on gcloud

   `kubectl create ns qa`
2. I created a folder "clinic_tai" contains yaml files:

> mysql-deployment.yaml mysql-service.yaml mysql-pvc.yaml
>   petclinic-deployment.yaml petclinic-service.yaml

3. I build these services

   `kubectl --namespace=qa apply -f ~/spring-boot-docker/examples/kubernetes-1.10/clinic_tai/`
4. I get detail of services
   `kubectl --namespace=qa get services

```
    NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)          AGE
mysql               ClusterIP      10.47.254.97    <none>            3306/TCP         25m
petclinic-service   LoadBalancer   10.47.243.216   104.196.116.129   8081:31781/TCP   25m
```

But, I can't access the application by using the url: 104.196.116.129:8081

Please check my yaml files 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yLCwr8Lvm3fyxoGVc5DQpKFBdDq2CxZv

Do you know what's wrong ?

Comment: Does it work in plain Docker?  Is your service correctly attached to the generated pods?  Do the ports in the service and the pods match up?  Reducing this to a [mcve] and including the relevant Kubernetes YAML in the question would be helpful.

Comment: what's the state of your pods? are they running correctly? have you tried creating a busybox in your namespace to test if you can access the service locally?
`kubectl -n qa run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=busybox sh` 

`wget -qO- petclinic-service:8081`

Comment: The pod state is running, please see my yaml files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yLCwr8Lvm3fyxoGVc5DQpKFBdDq2CxZv

Comment: @DavidMaze: When I run your command: it show "unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -qO-"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot access your yaml files but:

The problem can be in matching labels of the selectors in the pod.

If your pod has "**app=egg"** tag, but Service selector had **"name=egg".** Matching them fixed the access problem.

Just changed **"name: egg"** on the service selector, to **"app: egg"**. If you set the matchLabels on deployment.

I hope it helps.